# Call a method from another class in another application with FOSTRestBundle in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have the class file ex: Stats.php when i want to give an array with information from another method in another application and class file ex: Information.php.

File Stats.php

```
public function getStats()
{
 $myInformations = // here i want to get information from Information.php
 .
 .
 .
 return $myInformations;
}
```

In different application.
File Informations.php

```
/**
* Get all locales
* @FOS\View()
* @FOS\Get("/locales")
* @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
* @return mixed
*/
public function getLocales(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
  .
  .
  .
  return $locales;
}
```

How I call function getLocales from url: http://myhost.com/api/locales in function getStatus()?

Comment: Resolve with GuzzleBundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the GuzzleBundle as mentioned in your comment. You can just inject a client into the class containing `getStats()` or by making it ContainerAware and retrieving the guzzle-client by its service id from the container. If you don't have to set default options for your client, i.e. you just want to access a url you assume is always available for all environments from all places you could just create a new client with default values:

```
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Making a request with the client is described in the guzzle docs in the [Quickstart in section Sending Requests](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-requests):

```
$response = $guzzleClient->get('http://myhost.com/api/locales')
```

When the request was successful you can retrieve the locales by calling:

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContent();
```

Either casting `getBody()` to string or using `getContent()` is important here. Again refer to Guzzle's documentation particularly the section on [using responses](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses).

For example if you send a json-encoded string you can do something like:

```
$encodedLocales = $response->getBody()->getContent();
$decodedLocales = json_decode($encodedLocales, true);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new \Exception(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

There are many things that should be said about this approach such as it's fragile because it relies on a working network connection possibly to a different server, it's not easily testable, transfer exceptions are not handled gracefully, etc. pp. but for a simple proof of concept or asa starting point this should suffice.